# Sintaxe TypeScript

Tags: javascript, sintaxe, typescript

Estou estudando TypeScript porém não entendo qual o significado deste exemplo:

```
interface Person {
    firstname: string;
    lastname: string;
}

function greeter(person : Person) {
    return "Hello, " + person.firstname + " " + person.lastname;
}
```

Não entendo o uso do `interface`. Pelo que entendi, ele define uma espécie de novo "tipo" de variável, que nesse exemplo está sendo usado no trecho `person : Person` (outro trecho que não entendo), porém no script compilado não parece ter efeito algum:

```
function greeter(person) {
    return "Hello, " + person.firstname + " " + person.lastname;
}
```

Compilando apena o código abaixo, o resultado é o mesmo. Alguém poderia me ajudar a entender este ponto da sintaxe?

```
function greeter(person) {
    return "Hello, " + person.firstname + " " + person.lastname;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TypeScript é um superconjunto de Javascript, o objetivo da linguagem é fornecer uma tipagem forte para que programadores acostumados com C# escrevam Javascript de uma maneira mais "confortável". O código TypeScript não é executado no final, ele deverá ser "compilado" e o resultado será sempre um código Javascript.

O uso da interface no exemplo que você citou, "existe" apenas enquanto você está escrevendo o código TypeScript:

```
interface Person {
    firstname: string;
    lastname: string;
}
```

Esse código será útil para que o compilador, assim como a IDE do Visual Studio entenda que o objeto `person` possui apenas membros `firstname` e `lastname`

```
function greeter(person : Person) {
    return "Hello, " + person.firstname + " " + person.lastname;
}
```

Pra que isso serve? Para evitar que cometamos erros, incluir suporte a intellisense e uma gama de recursos similares aos que o Visual Studio oferece com C# (renomear variáveis, ir até a definição de um membro, etc).

Nesse exemplo, ao contrário de Javascript, em TypeScript o compilador não permitiria que tentássemos acessar um membro não declarado do objeto `person`:

```
person.age; // isso retornaria um erro de compilação
```

Uma vantagem que experimentei e gostei muito foi a possibilidade de baixar pacotes de definição de bibliotecas existentes (procure no nuget por typescript DefinitelyTyped) como jquery, googlemaps api, para serem incluídos como referência em arquivos TypeScript. Achei uma maravilha a experiência de usar a API do Google Maps com intellisense, sem precisar ir buscar a documentação a cada instante.

Em suma, o objetivo TypeScript é manter a sintaxe de Javascript (é possível escrever apenas código Javascript mesmo em TS) incluindo tipagem forte com suporte a escrita de classes, com herança e polimorfismo enquanto estamos escrevendo nosso código.